# Obscure C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ostream& f(ostream& os) {
    return os << "hi";
}

int main() {
    cout << "hello " << f << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And somehow this works - the output is "hello hi". How does this get interpreted by the compiler? I don't understand how a function can be inserted into a stream.

Comment: There is an overloaded `operator<<` that accepts a function and calls it. How exactly is it obscure?

Comment: That's the way that various `std::endl` or `std::flush` overloads work, too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`std::ostream` has an `operator<<` overload that receives a pointer to a function with the signature such as the one you wrote ([number 11 in this list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

which just calls the given function passing itself as argument. This overload (along with several similar others) is there to allow you to implement *stream manipulators*, i.e. stuff that you output in the stream with an `<<` and changes the state of the stream from there. For example, our version of the (incorrectly) ubiquitous `std::endl` may be implemented as

```
std::ostream &myendl(std::ostream &s) {
    s<<'\n';
    s.flush();
    return s;
}
```

which can then be used exactly as the "regular" `std::endl`:

```
std::cout<<"Hello, World!"<<myendl;
```

(the actual implementation is templated and a bit more complicated because it has to work even with wide streams, but you got the idea)

Answer (score 8):

`std::ostream::operator<<` has an overload which accepts a function as parameter; and the body of that overload is to invoke the function given.

This is exactly how `endl` works in fact. `endl` is actually a function similar to:

```
ostream &endl(ostream &os)
{
    os << '\n'; 
    os.flush(); 
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I'd have to check, but I don't think there is any template involved (ignoring the fact that `ostream` is an instatiation of `basic_ostream`). AFAIR, there are only two overloads for functions taking an `ostream` and `ios_base`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt well, the template parameters are `CharT` and `Traits`. Will edit to clarify since that is misleading as you point out.